# Dynamic Button list on dropdown dataBound gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to Create Dynamic Button List on dropdown dataBound .Not on Init() or in Constructor ...But it gives error every time ..

```
Control 'ctl00' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server
```

My Dropdown is already inside form with runat="server"

this is mark up :

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 100%">
               <asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="100%" ID="ddlLecturer" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLecturer_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" OnDataBound="ddlLecturer_DataBound">
        </asp:DropDownList>

    </form>
</body>
```

this is my code :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
    //fill dropdown

}

    protected void ddlLecturer_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//alternate --didnot work out
        //List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        //{
        //    Button newButton = new Button();
        //    newButton.ID = "btn1";
        //    buttons.Add(newButton);
        //    this.Controls.Add(newButton);

        //}

        CreateDynamicButton();
    }


    private void CreateDynamicButton()
    {
        // Create a Button object 
        Button dynamicButton = new Button();

        // Set Button properties
        dynamicButton.Height = 40;
        dynamicButton.Width = 300;
        dynamicButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dynamicButton.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        //dynamicButton.Location = new Point(20, 150);
        dynamicButton.Text = "I am Dynamic Button";
        //dynamicButton.Name = "DynamicButton";
        //dynamicButton.Font = new Font("Georgia", 16);

        //// Add a Button Click Event handler
        //dynamicButton.Click += new EventHandler(DynamicButton_Click);

        // Add Button to the Form. Placement of the Button
        // will be based on the Location and Size of button
        Controls.Add(dynamicButton);
    }
}
```

What I am missing ?

Comment: Use Page.Controls.Add(dynamicButton). Best approach is to have a div with runat=server as below

myDiv.Controls.Add(add_img_popup); <br/> This is already been answered in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993808/asp-net-button-object-runat-server-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message is self explanatory. It is not complaining about your DropDownList but complaining about the dynamic button not being inside the form.

You can use `form1.Controls.Add(dynamicButton)`. This will ensure the control is added within `<form></form>` tags.

You see there is another option `Page.Controls.Add(dynamicButton)` but this will not work and throw the same error message as the control will be added within the page but outside of `<form></form>` tags.

The cleaner option would be to have a server side place holder of some sort with in the `<form></form>` tags. For example `<div runat="server" id="placeHolder></div>`
Now you should be able to add the control using `placeHolder.Controls.Add(dynamicButton)`

**Additional Info**

As for adding dynamic controls you have to be aware that the controls need to be recreated on postback. Also the [ASP.NET page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) is crucial.

Here is a small example. Not the cleanest solution; but it is for you to get an idea.

*Basically based on the dropdown selection, a dynamic button is created. And when you click on the dynamic button it displays a message specific to that button.*

**Markup**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="page1.aspx.cs" Inherits="test.page1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLecturer" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ddlLecturer_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Lecturer1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Lecturer2</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

    </div>
    <div id="placeHolder" runat="server">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;

namespace test
{
    public partial class page1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["dynamicBtnSession"] != null)
            {
                CreateDynamicButton((string)Session["dynamicBtnSession"]);
            }
        }

        protected void ddlLecturer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            placeHolder.Controls.Remove(FindControl("dynamicBtn"));
            lblOutput.Text = string.Empty;
            if (ddlLecturer.SelectedValue != "Select")
            {
                Session["dynamicBtnSession"] = ddlLecturer.SelectedValue;
                CreateDynamicButton(ddlLecturer.SelectedValue);
            }
            else
            {
                Session["dynamicBtnSession"] = null;
            }
        }

        private void CreateDynamicButton(string val)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Height = 40;
            btn.Width = 120;
            btn.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            btn.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            btn.ID = "dynamicBtn";
            btn.Text = "Dynamic Button " + val;
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
            placeHolder.Controls.Add(btn);
        }

        void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblOutput.Text = "You clicked " + ((Button)sender).Text;
        }
    }
}
```